# How to suppress exp_spawn translating " to \?

Tags: tcl, expect, openssh, double-quotes

I am using `tcl8.5` on windows 7. I need to use spawn with `openssh`. The username has double-quotes (e.g. abc"). I can use `openssh` to login the remote device with this account when I am using it in a command window:

```
D:\Program Files\OpenSSH\bin>ssh 192.168.0.253 -labc"\""
```

...
abc"@192.168.0.253's password:

(the correct username is displayed by openssh)

However, when I use spawn ssh with the same syntax in a script, the `"` is translated to `\`
When I enter the correct password, access is denied.

```
exp_spawn "$sshClient" "192.168.0.253" -labc\"\\\"\"
=>
abc\\""@192.168.0.253
```

The following attempt also shows " being translated to \

```
exp_spawn "$sshClient" "192.168.0.253" -labc\"
=>
abc\@192.168.0.253
```

Could anyone show me the correct syntax please? Or is there any option in exp_spawn I need to enable?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
exp_spawn $sshClient 192.168.0.253 {-labc"}
```